# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: Error inflating class

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-inflate

Running into a slight Inflation issue while trying to implement the micode open source compass into my app. So I am trying to figure out how to fix this. Another set of eyes looking at this would be good. So here we go:

Here is the class that this is relating to:

```
package styckz.com.clearpicturemode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CompassView extends ImageView {
private float mDirection;
private Drawable compass;

public CompassView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mDirection = 0.0f;
    compass = null;
}

public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mDirection = 0.0f;
    compass = null;
}

public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mDirection = 0.0f;
    compass = null;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (compass == null) {
        compass = getDrawable();
        compass.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(mDirection, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    compass.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

public void updateDirection(float direction) {
    mDirection = direction;
    invalidate();
}

}
```

So here we are... I tried turning that class above from public to static to no avail as per the request in another thread and it did not work... Maybe I am doing something wrong? All that did was make the class name highlight red below it and claim that static was invalid.

Any ideas?

Here is the Layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_compass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/prompt" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_direction"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                    </ImageView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_angle"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/background_compass" />

                    <net.micode.compass.CompassView
                        android:id="@+id/compass_pointer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/compass" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/miui_cover" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/location_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/getting_location"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#7FFFFFFF" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/low_accuracy_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dip"
    layout="@*android:layout/transient_notification"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Also here is the logcat of doom:

```
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity        ComponentInfo{styckz.com.clearpicturemode/styckz.com.clearpicturemode.CompassActivity}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: Error inflating class  net.micode.compass.CompassView
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: Error inflating class net.micode.compass.CompassView
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at styckz.com.clearpicturemode.CompassActivity.onCreate(CompassActivity.java:99)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    ... 11 more
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.micode.compass.CompassView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/styckz.com.clearpicturemode-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/styckz.com.clearpicturemode-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
11-22 14:22:30.667: E/AndroidRuntime(16140):    ... 26 more
```

Comment: You need to post your xml file as the problem is there.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that!

Comment: by the error it appears you may have your paths mixed up as it is looking for CompasView in `net.micode.compass.CompassView` where you have compasview in `styckz.com.clearpicturemode`

Comment: I added the layout @Szymon | Alright how do I go about changing that @tyczj?

Comment: probably a library inclusion issue.

Comment: from your code the package to that view is `styckz.com.clearpicturemode`, not `net.micode.compass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you have the wrong path in your xml.

you have `CompassView` as being located in `net.micode.compass.` but it is actually located in `styckz.com.clearpicturemode`

so change that in your xml

this

```
<net.micode.compass.CompassView
   android:id="@+id/compass_pointer"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:src="@drawable/compass" />
```

should look like this

```
<styckz.com.clearpicturemode.CompassView
   android:id="@+id/compass_pointer"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:src="@drawable/compass" />
```

Comment: Alright now I need to find this transient notification thing in the include section.